# How to enforce style rules in a messy code base?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

I've inherited a team who uses TFS 2012, with **no checkin-rules whatsoever**.

Our code base is often polluted by poor quality code, modifications to files that should be read-only, almost no-unit test coverage.

**What can we use that will block poor-quality checkins?** We currently all have resharper licenses.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs here.

Comment: You said there are no check-in rules whatsoever. So what about adding some then?

Comment: What about setting up a D.O.D. E.G. a minimum of 80% code-coverage. Besides that, create features branches, that can only be submitted into develop or master by pull request. In TFS you are able to set a minimum of code-reviewers per pull request, before it can be approved.

Comment: @Evk that is my question, how/where do we add checkin rules?

Comment: @max where can we set this minimum code coverage? where do we set minimum of code -reviewers?

Comment: You can start with reading this for example: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' see: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies

Comment: @Evk thats for tfs 2015

Comment: @max thats for tfs 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using Resharper, I would recommend the [Code Cleanup feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Code_Cleanup__Running_Code_Cleanup.html). It allows you to create a set of formatting rules that can be applied to a file when your run Code Cleanup. My team has a common Resharper settings file for code formatting that is checked into TFS.

After creating the rules, getting it checked in, getting buy in from your team, and setting up the file on everyone ones machine, I would recommend the following pattern:

- Open / Check out file from TFS
- If the code needs to be cleaned up, run code clean up
- Check In the code that has been cleaned up
- Check out the code again
- Make edits

If you don't check in the code in until after you have cleaned it up and made your edit, the diff is very hard to tell what was changed.

You will have to get the buy in from your team to start running code cleanup. Either that or Code Cleanup is supported on a folder, project, and solution level, so you could just open all of the solutions and clean the up yourself.

Comment: this will not work at enforcing standards, since this relies on manual work from each developer -- i am thinking of more of a server-side solution that will do this

Comment: Two things. First, _I've inherited a team_ makes it sound like you are in charge and should be able to make a requirement to run code cleanup. Second, I don't think having something change your code after it is checked in is a good idea because it removes responsibility from the developer if the build breaks or something goes wrong in production because that tool didn't format the code with the same logic.

Comment: it would fail the build if it does not fulfill syntax requirements